# Empty custom error page (JSF)

Tags: jsf, primefaces, custom-error-pages

Hello I hope this wasnt asked before, I didnt find anything that helped me...

I have an custom errorpage (error.xhtml) containing this:

```
<h2>Error!</h2>
Message: #{pfExceptionHandler.message} <br/>
StackTrace: <h:outputText value="#{pfExceptionHandler.formattedStackTrace}" escape="false" /> <br />
<p>The error message is: #{requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}</p>
${requestScope['javax.servlet.error.message']}
```

These are all variants I found here, but neithertheless the htmloutput is:

```
<h2>Error!</h2>
Message:  <br />
StackTrace:  <br />
<p>The error message is: </p>
```

My faces-config.xml contains this (for primeface ajax exception handler like in showcase):

```
<application>
    <el-resolver>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>

<factory>
    <exception-handler-factory>org.primefaces.application.exceptionhandler.PrimeExceptionHandlerFactory</exception-handler-factory>
</factory>
```

And my web.xml contains this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/error.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I also tried

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.apache.myfaces.ERROR_HANDLING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

But I also have the same result. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: For testing this I disable MySql and I see in logfile that there was an SQLException thrown.

Kind regards